# No USB connection from MacBook Pro to Arduino

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I have a Apple M2 MacBook Pro with Sonoma 14.0 installed and a Arduino Micro. While the connection was working just fine in the past, it stopped working all of a sudden two days ago and it seems, that the MacOS is not able to create a port on "`/dev/...`" anymore. Ever since then I try to make it work again, using all combinations of two different Arduino Micros, three different USB C Ports on the MacBook, two different USB C to USB A/B Adapters (Apple manufactor) and five different USB A/B to Micro USB cables. Nothing worked so far. The error message I see is this:

```
macbook: log stream | grep -i usb
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242472+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setActive(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] active: YES
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242512+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportStateUSB2::setActive_block_invoke(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] active: 0 [NO] -> 1 [YES]
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242523+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setActive(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] active: YES (transportType: 2 [USB2])
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242883+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::_updateTRMState(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Updating TRM state...
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242911+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportStateUSB::calculateAuthorizationState(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Calculating authorization state...
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242921+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::calculateAuthorizationState(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Calculating authorization state...
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242930+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::calculateAuthorizationState_block_invoke(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] *** UNRT ***
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242951+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::handleStateChange(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Handling state change...
2023-10-02 19:40:25.242963+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Sending 3 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.243291+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::handleServiceReregistration(): [Port-USB-C@2/USB2] Re-registering service...
2023-10-02 19:40:25.243298+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::registerService(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Registering service USB2@(null)... (transportType: 2, provider: Port-USB-C@2)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.243877+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.243952+0200 0x1766f    Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOServiceNotificationManager::sendMessages(): [Port-USB-C@2] Sending 2 message(s)... (m_propertyChanged: YES)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406728+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[66] 0x00000100000e8000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x0000010000048420 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406760+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406854+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[67] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x0000010000048430 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406868+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406938+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:25.406998+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:26.408296+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:26.531998+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[70] 0x0000010000058000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x0000010000048460 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:26.532038+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:26.532125+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[71] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x0000010000048470 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:26.532139+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:26.532205+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:26.532251+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:27.533525+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717032+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[74] 0x00000100000e8000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x00000100000484a0 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717071+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717179+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[75] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x00000100000484b0 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717194+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717265+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:27.717321+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:28.718667+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964593+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[78] 0x0000010000058000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x00000100000484e0 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964664+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964773+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[79] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x00000100000484f0 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964792+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964872+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:28.964922+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:29.966222+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:30.269807+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[82] 0x00000100000e8000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x0000010000048520 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:30.269847+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:30.269938+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[83] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x0000010000048530 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:30.269954+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:30.270023+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:30.270071+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:31.271023+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639097+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[86] 0x0000010000058000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x0000010000048560 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639131+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639222+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[87] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x0000010000048570 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639235+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639301+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:31.639356+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:32.640641+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068454+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[90] 0x00000100000e8000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x00000100000485a0 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068505+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068586+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[91] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x00000100000485b0 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068598+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068656+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:33.068705+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
2023-10-02 19:40:34.070053+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 3)
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560060+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[94] 0x0000010000058000 00000000 01002c01 got result 0x00000100000485e0 04000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560084+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::setAddress: completed with result code 4
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560205+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::executeCommand: command[95] 0x0000000000000000 00000000 01013c01 got result 0x00000100000485f0 13000000 01008401 after 0ms (enqueued 0ms)
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560220+0200 0x6b9      Error       0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBXHCI) AppleT8112USBXHCICommandRing: AppleUSBXHCICommandRing::stopEndpoint: completed with result code 19
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560299+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::createDevice: failed to create device (0xe00002bc)
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560318+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOUSBHostFamily) usb-drd1-port-hs@01100000: AppleUSBHostPort::disconnect: persistent enumeration failures
2023-10-02 19:40:34.560352+0200 0x6b9      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOAccessoryManager) IOPortTransportState::setNominalSignalingFrequencies(): [Port-USB-C@2: USB2] Setting nominal signaling frequencies... (nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz: YES, nominalSignalingFrequenciesHz.count: 1)
```

Do I need to rerun some setup or install additional software for a USB data connection from macOS to and Arduino board on Sonoma?

Comment: Hopefully someone that has been using the beta of Sonoma or [another IDE can chime in](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/ide-2-1-2-and-mac-os-x-14-sonoma/1150897). I’m not up to speed on things of late.